# TelerikGrid is too large after ajax

Tags: ajax, telerik, slider, radgrid

I have implemented to RadGrid inline inserting and editing. 
Some templates are in edit mode larger, then in standard mode, RadGrid is exactly over whole screen. In edit/insert mode is a little larger.
It is not problem. Just compromise.

Until I reload whole page after each event, everything was OK.

When I set it as ajax, there is a several small acceptable problem, but worst for me is:

**When grid is larger then screen, after refresh in browsers is slider. After ajax there is no slider.**

In worst case I make smaller templates, to be same large as standard mode, but it is not good solution from some reasons.

Do you know what with it?

Answer (score 0):

**When grid is larger then screen, after refresh in browsers is slider. After ajax there is no slider.**

? 
If u meant by Slider Scrollbars then the solution is to put your RadGrid inside a panel and it should solve it:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="Server"
      Height="300px" Width="400px"
      BackColor="Aqua" ScrollBars="Auto">

<Telerik:RadGrid Id=........./>

</asp:Panel>
```

regards